# Why has tidyverse's mutate/fct_relevel changed data beyond just x-bin positions?

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

I have a simple biomass dataset. In one frame, I've used fct_relevel on the treatment categories to reorganise them on the x-axis as "low, median, high", and to double check what it looked like I made another frame where I didn't. The code I used for the mutation is:

```
CELgra <- basic_ABV %>%
  mutate(range_point = fct_relevel(range_point, 'low', 'median', 'high')) %>%
  filter(species == "CELgra")
```

To double check, it was the same, minus the mutate function line. Then I made a simple box plot:

```
CELgra_ABV_box <- ggplot(CELgra, aes(x = range_point, y = ABV)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  xlab(NULL)+
  ylab("Total Aboveground Biomass (mg)") +
  theme_bw() 

CELgra_ABV_box
```

The non-mutated frame looks like this:
[image]

Whereas the mutated frame looks very different...
[image]

I don't understand why it's doing this. Is there something going on in the mutate() function I've missed?

Comment: what's the name of the dataset

Comment: basic_ABV is the dataset. CELgra is the subset frame

Comment: if you don't post the data we can't reproduce the error :(

Comment: I'm not sure if this is right, but I uploaded it to GitHub here: https://github.com/Glae-Nara/alpine-data-pub/blob/master/Basic%20Responses%20EDIT%2019-08-20.csv

Comment: try running this command `any( CELgra != (unchanged %>% filter(species == "CELgra")), rm.na=T)`

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error fct_relevel seems to behave as expected. plus the graph seems to have just zoomed in cuz somehow that outlier `median class` point disappeared

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the dataset and testing if the unchanged one is different from the changed data.frame. I couldn't reproduce the error. as the factors have been moved around as expected notice the first graph you have `high low median` then `low high median` it's basically the same graph just rearranged, as I mentioned above in the comments the outlier point in the `median class` have somehow disappeared that's why the graph zoomed in.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(raster)
library(BIOMASS)
library(forcats)
unchanged <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Glae-Nara/alpine-data-pub/master/Basic%20Responses%20EDIT%2019-08-20.csv')
CELgra <- unchanged %>%
  mutate(range_point = fct_relevel(range_point, 'low', 'median', 'high')) %>%
  filter(species == "CELgra")

CELgra_ABV_box <- ggplot(CELgra, aes(x = range_point, y = ABV)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  xlab(NULL)+
  ylab("Total Aboveground Biomass (mg)") +
  theme_bw() 

CELgra_ABV_box
```

[image]

```r
unchanged %>% filter(species == "CELgra") %>%  ggplot( aes(x = range_point, y = ABV)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  xlab(NULL)+
  ylab("Total Aboveground Biomass (mg)") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]